# How to make a button that slides on click and changes background theme with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am usually a back-end developer that tries to become fullstack and I came to a little problem.

What I want to do is have a button that on click slides to the other side and changes the background. I am familiar with how to make an event on click and actually change the background. My problem is how to make the CSS so it looks good.

Lets say I have black and white themes. I want to have a box with white and black sides. When I click on it I want one of the sides to shift.

Here is how I want it to look.

[image]

The idea is to click on the box and the black part to move. Basically the white part is the background and the black part is the button that slides with some animation. Then the black part switches its color to opposite of the current background.

Basically the colors just swap but with cool sliding animation.

I know that I need one `div` for the box with background the current background.

I also know that I need another `div` to be the actual part that moves with background opposite of the current one.The inner dif will have a button inside of it that on click will call the function that changes the background.

What I can do so far is

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="slider">
        <button onClick="changeBackGroundColor()"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `slider` div will have half the width of `box` and full height of `box`.

Now comes the tricky part - how can I add `if` in css so that I can always check what is the current background and make the background of `slider` the opposite of the current one?

Also - how can I make it slide to the border of the box? I need to make the sliding in both directions. From right to left when the theme is white and from left to write when its black.

Comment: I don't usually link to w3schools, but this seems to be what you're looking for: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know its called "toggled switch".